# Implement Web Services in PHP & JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web-services

I want to use web services with ajax php and javacript, thied this exemple but I still have this error. 
I tried a lot of code, please someone help me.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxxx/login.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1

index.html

```
<html><head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="jsjsjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='logindiv'>     
        <label>Username:</label>
            <input name="username"  id="username" type="text">
        <label>Password:</label>
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password">
            <input value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick='chk_ajax_login_with_php();'>
        <div id='status'></div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

jsjsjs.js

```
function chk_ajax_login_with_php(){
  var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password=document.getElementById("password").value;  
    var params = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
           var url = "xxxxx/login.php";
                $.ajax({
                               type: 'POST',
                               url: url,
                               dataType: 'html',
                               data: params,
                               beforeSend: function() {
                                 document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= 'checking...'  ;},
                               complete: function() { },
                               success: function(html) {
                                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= html;
                                     if(html=="success"){                                       
                                       window.location ="/test.php"                                      
                                     }                                      
                                }
                       });     
}
```

login.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['username'] != null and $_POST['username'] != "" and $_POST['password'] != null and $_POST['password'] != ""){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
}
if($username == "youssef" and $password=="4656" ){
echo "Nice";
}
else { echo "nono";}
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' Why is it not showing when I use POSTMAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w)

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL your are requesting from is not on the same domain as the request originates browser security will prevent the request completing. This is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

To work around this you will need to make a JSONP request or use CORS, assuming the third party supports them, or make a server-side proxy to make the request for you and make the AJAX  request to this local URL.